# Nested models in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

If I have a deeply-nested model graph, coming from the server (a lot of children objects, some of which arrays). Is it a good practice to turn each of the children of the object, into Models and Collections respective, when I turn the object into a Model? This will be handy because it will reduce the confusion of what should be called how. For example, it is much clearer to have something like that:

```
myModel.get("child1").get("collection1").get(0);
```

instead of:

```
myModel.get("child1").collection1[0];
```

On another side, it might turn into a performance hell if we are trying to convert these at runtime, especially if the object graph is really deep.

What is the best practice there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Backbone.relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/) to take care of it for you.

Comment: Ok but what would be the best practice using vanilla BB?

Comment: Vanilla backbone has no opinion. I did though: Before I discovered Backbone.relational, I would have an event listener on `change` to create the models and and collections. This is only for models/collections that had methods I needed to use; was not worth the hassle for dumb data.